# Setup a Synapse self-hosted Integration Runtime unattended

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse

How can I install a self-hosted Synapse integration runtime on an Azure VM with CD pipeline?

I created a pipeline that deploys the data lake, Synapse workspace and a VM for the self-hosted IR. The pipeline also joins the VM to the domain to access our internal resources. However, I haven't figured out a way to configure the IR with the pipeline.

It would be OK for me to hardcode the URL to the executable, even if future deployments continue to use outdated versions of the IR (assuming new versions come up between deployments), but how could I install the IR on the pipeline?